# making a graph using lists in C++

Tags: c++, list, graph

I got the list of vertices to work. Now I'm trying to put in the edges into each vertex but when I try to put in the adjacent vertex into an edge from the original vertex list it won't work. I use an iterator to find the vertex at the beginning of the edge and another iterator to find the vertex at the end of the edge (street). For some reason when i try setting the edge's vertex pointer to an element in the vertex list it won't allow it. here's the error "Error  1   error C2679: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::_List_iterator<_Mylist>'":

main:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<list>
#include <fstream>
#include<cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include<sstream>
#include "global.h"
#include "edge.h"
#include "vertex.h"
using namespace std;

int main ( int argc, char *argv[] ){
if(argc != 4){
    cout<< "usage: "<< argv[0]<<"<filename>\n";
}
else{

    ifstream map_file (argv[3]);

    if(!map_file.is_open()){
        cout<<"could not open file\n";
    }
    else{
        Edge tempe;
        Vertex tempx;

        std::string line;
        std::ifstream input(argv[3]);
        int xsect;
        int safety;
        int change = 0;
        int i = 0;
        int vert = 0;
        int adjvert = 0;
        int dist = 0;
        //k and m keep track of iteration through list
        int k = 0;
        int m = 0;
        std:string xname;

        std::list<Vertex> xSectionList;
        std::list<Edge> EdgeList;




        while (getline(input, line))
        {

          std::istringstream iss(line);
          if(line == "INTERSECTIONS:"){
              change =1;
              i = 0;
          }
          else if(line == "STREETS:"){
              change = 2;
              i = 0;
          }

          if( change ==1 && i != 0){
            iss >> xsect >> safety;

           std::getline(iss, xname);

           tempx.xsect = xsect;
           tempx.danger = safety;
           tempx.xstreets = xname;

           xSectionList.push_back(tempx);

          }

         else if(change ==2 && i!=0){ 

                iss >> vert >> adjvert >> dist;


              std::list<Vertex>::iterator it = xSectionList.begin();

              while(it->xsect != vert || k != xSectionList.size()+1) {
                it++;
                k++;
             }

              std::list<Vertex>::iterator tit = xSectionList.begin();

              while(tit->xsect != adjvert || m != xSectionList.size()+1) {
                tit++;
                m++;

             }

              //tempe.adjvertex = tit;
              tempe.distance = dist;
              it->EdgeList.push_back(tempe);
              it->EdgeList.begin()->adjvertex = tempx;
               //std::getline(iss, xname);
              }

           //cout<<xsect<< " " << safety << " " << xname<<endl;

          i++;
        }



        std::list<Vertex>::iterator kit = xSectionList.begin();
        std::list<Edge>::iterator lit = kit->EdgeList.begin();

        //std::cout << it->xsect<< " " << it->danger << " "<< it->xstreets;

        for(lit = kit->EdgeList.begin(); lit != kit->EdgeList.end(); lit++) {
            cout << kit->xsect << "" << lit->adjvertex->xsect << "" << lit->distance<< endl;
         }


        }
    }

getchar();
}
```

header vertex`

```
#ifndef VERTEX_H
#define VERTEX_H
#include<list>
#include<string>
#include "global.h"

struct Vertex_{
int xsect;
int danger;
std::string xstreets;

std::list<Edge> EdgeList;
/*struct Vertex_ *next;
struct Vertex_ *prev;*/
};

#endif
```

edge header

```
#ifndef EDGE_H
#define EDGE_H

#include "global.h"
#include "vertex.h"
struct Edge_{
Vertex *adjvertex;
int distance;

/*struct edge *next;
struct edge *prev;*/
};

#endif
```

file example i'm scanning data from where intersections are vertices and streets are edges:

```
397 0.6 Drachman and 27th
398 0.5 Drachman and 28th
399 0.3 Drachman and 29th
400 0.8 Drachman and 30th

STREETS:
1   2   0.5
2   3   1.0
3   4   0.9
4   5   0.7
5   6   0.1
```

Comment: What line number produces the error?

Comment: starting from line number 94. i put it in comments to try what's on line number 97 but that didn't work either.

Comment: if anyone still has answers it would be awesome. Still giving me the same error.

Answer (score 0):

An iterator works like a pointer, but it typically isn't a pointer.  You'll need to do something like

```
tempe.adjvertex = &*tit;
```

`*tit` gets the vertex that the iterator is currently on, so `&*tit` gets a pointer to that vertex.

Comment: perfect thanks. got rid of the error. Now for some reason i get an error and it's aborting because of the while loop iterations at line 81

Answer (score 0):

I would just use boost graph unless this is a homework assignment.

Comment: this is a homework assignment need to use lists. The error went away with @Vaughn Cato's answer but now im having trouble with the while loops. i guess i can't use the iterator's data and compare them to an actual int. Any clues?